# My recursive method doesn't stop after it reaches the end of the method

Tags: java

I would like to generate some random coordinates, from a start location in the `north(x=10,y=0)`, `west(x=0,y=10)`, `east(x=20,y=10)` or `south(x=10,y=20)`. (for a random dungeongenerator, just for a hopefully funny project ;^) )

```
private void generateDungeon(int x, int y, int groesse) {

    //System.out.println("groesse: " +groesse);
    int tempX = this.neueKoordinaten.nextInt(2);
    int tempY = this.neueKoordinaten.nextInt(2);

    if(tempX == 0 && tempY== 0) {
        this.generateDungeon(x, y, groesse);
    }
    if(tempY==1) {  
        y = y + (1 * this.yFaktor);
    }else if(tempX == 1) {
        x = x + (1 * this.xFaktor);
    }

    this.aktuelleKoordinaten = new Point(x,y);
    //System.out.println("aktuelleKoordinaten: " +this.aktuelleKoordinaten);
    this.koordinatenListe.add(this.aktuelleKoordinaten);

    groesse++;

    if(groesse <= 4) {
        System.out.println("???" + groesse);
        this.generateDungeon(x, y,groesse);
    }   
    System.out.println("test");
}
```

I thought, that after my "groesse" (size) reaches a certain point (4 in this case), my method will stop calling itself, but it doesn't.

For some reasons it keep jumping back to the if with `tempY==1` after it reaches the end point of the method (the testoutput).
Sometimes for like 20 times, sometimes only once or twice.
I really don't understand this behaviour.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I know, that's because if tempX == 0 && tempY == 0, the generator have to try again. (because I would'nt get new coordinates out of it)

Comment: What does `this.neueKoordinaten.nextInt(2)` do and how likely is it that it will return `0`?

Comment: It returns a 0 or a 1. 
i want to archive a movemont on the y or x axis, but not on both at the same time. (I prefer the movement on the y axis, that's why it's over the if(x==1) thing,
I think it's pretty much half of the time that it returns a zero, but can't confirm it. Never tested it ;D

Comment: So you have a 25% probability to get 0/0 and start a recursive descent?

Comment: What you describe as "jumping back" is probably a new recursive invocation of the method. Step through it in a debugger, and watch how the stack grows each time it "jumps back".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm right in thinking that `this.neueKoordinaten.nextInt(2)` generates a random int between 0 and 1... Than you have 25% to hit

```
if(tempX == 0 && tempY== 0) {
    this.generateDungeon(x, y, groesse);
}
```

snippet each time your method runs. It runs 4 or 5 times (depends on whether you start groesse with 0 or 1) when it doesn't hit that. If it does however, this line is your new point of start, it will run it those 4 or 5 times (probably less, depending on `groesse` value when that happens) before continuing with what it was doing, resulting in unpredictable amount of executions.

Judging by comments, what you did want was just to reroll again, not start the entire function again:

```
while(tempX == 0 && tempY == 0){
    tempX = this.neueKoordinaten.nextInt(2);
    tempY = this.neueKoordinaten.nextInt(2);
}
```

Or, if you prefer to restart again indicate, that this branch is finished:

```
if(tempX == 0 && tempY== 0) {
    this.generateDungeon(x, y, groesse);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Jep, that was my mistake. Just found out the same.
I didn't knew that if you restart the function, that you have to end the rest of the function.
I thought if I call my function recursive, the rest of the function is terminated.
Nice answer, good sir ;^)

Answer (score 2):

Hard to see the complete story from this snippet but it looks as though your first if statement is passing and you're calling generateDungeon without incrementing groesse. This would explain why it looks like the code is "jumping back" to the following line if(tempY==1) because that is the first line after the method call.

I'd suggest debugging through the method step by step, keeping track of groesse and also the values of tempx/tempy

Comment: Hi, I tried that allready. 
The thing is (I should have mentioned this) is that after I reach the testoutput it calls the testoutput a few times before it jumps back to if(tempY==1).
until my groesse is >4 it works exactly as I would expect. But after that, it doesn't anymore. Would it be helpfull to post all the code?